# How to drop a table with register form (SQL Injection) (closed)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, code-injection

I want to test my site for SQL Injection and tried to delete the table with my userlist. I visited a lot of web pages but couldn't find a working code.

I have my register form with username and password. I didn't protect it at all so it has to be possible to delete that table.

**I tried to enter many things in the password field like for example this:**

```
''; drop table blog_posts; '
```

**The code of my register form is the following:**

```
if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tutorial', 'root', '');
    $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO login (username, password) VALUES (:username, :password)");
    $statement->execute(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
    echo "done!";

}
```

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: I know, I normally save my passwords in a hash. This was just a quick written example to understand how SQL injection works, but I didn't work. It was my aim to make this easy to hack.

Comment: You're using a prepared statement with bound parameters... which is the absolute best way to **prevent** SQL injection, so yeah, it's not going to work!

Comment: really? Oh, thanks xd That wasn't my intention.

Comment: If you want it to be hackable, try `$statement = $pdo->query("INSERT INTO login (username, password) VALUES ('$username', '$password')");` - gotta admit though, **inadvertently using best-practices** is a new one on me! May it long continue :D